# Retorno payload em branco, ao realizar retorno para aplicação WEB em Golang

Tags: api, rest, golang

Estou verificando na API se o email do usuário já está cadastrado e retorna uma mensagem de aviso. Mesmo realizando as requisições o payload retorna vazio.

Mesmo debugando e sabendo que o payload do lado da api está com a informação ele retorna vazio.

Um amigo, me recomendou fazer uma interface e jogar a informação dentro dele, tornando uma interface dentro de outra interface, porém não funcionou.

Obrigado.

```
func CreateUsuario(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

      var util util.StructApp

      msg := []interface{}{}
      msg = append(msg, "Erro")

      util.RespondWithJSON(responseWriter, http.StatusCreated, msg)
}




func (appStruct *StructApp) RespondWithJSON(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
        var responseSuccess response.ResponseSuccess
        responseSuccess.Records = payload
        lenPayload := reflect.ValueOf(payload)
        responseSuccess.Meta.RecordCount = 1
        responseSuccess.Meta.Limit = 1

        if lenPayload.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            responseSuccess.Meta.Limit = lenPayload.Len()
            responseSuccess.Meta.RecordCount = lenPayload.Len()
        }

        response, _ := json.Marshal(responseSuccess)
        responseWriter.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        responseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
        responseWriter.Write(response)
    }
```

> ```
> {"meta":{"limit":1,"offset":0,"recordCount":1},"records":{}}
> ```

Comment: Olá Caio, poderia adicionar o retorno?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, adicionado o retorno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

peguei seu exemplo e removi a struct e troquei o status, creio que isso vai lhe ajudar!

```
//Ping representa o teste de ping
func Ping(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var t util.StructApp
    t.RespondWithJSON(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, "pong")
}
```

Meu retorno

```
{"meta":{"limit":1,"offset":0,"recordCount":1},"records":"pong"}
```